# Write a variable value from one file to another file

Tags: shell

I am trying to read a variable value from test.sh and write it in file2.txt by replacing the word COMP in file2.txt

I am using below command to achieve this but not possible

```
sed -r 's/(echo "$NAME" test.sh)/COMP/' file2.txt
```

for your reference

test.sh contains

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME=RAJ
```

Answer (score 1):

To read variables from a file you can use the `source` or `.` command. Then use double quotes to make the shell expand variables while preserving whitespace:

```
source test.sh && sed -i "s/$NAME/COMP/g" file2.txt
```

The BSD sed command takes the `-i` option but requires a suffix for the backup (but an empty suffix is permitted). So if you’re running on Mac or BSD system, use:

```
source test.sh && sed -i '' "s/$NAME/COMP/g" file2.txt
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @1218985, but its not working.  i expect to achieve in single line command

Comment: can you suggest me the answer like in following format      
                               **sed -i "s/(source test.sh | $NAME )/COMP/g" file2.txt**

Comment: @k4jc You can do source test.sh && sed -i "s/$NAME/COMP/g" file2.txt if you need a one liner

Comment: thank you, can i use the source command, if i have multiple variables in test.sh file and all these variable values to be written in .txt file

Answer (score 1):

You've got your sed `s///` backwards, I think. You want to search for `COMP` and replace the value of `$NAME`

```sh
. test.sh
sed "s/COMP/$NAME/" file2.txt
```

If $NAME can contain a slash character, it will break sed's `s///` command, so you need to escape slashes in the variable expansion

```sh
. test.sh
replacement=${NAME//\//\\\/}
sed "s/COMP/$replacement/" file2.txt

# NAME='a/b/c/d'
# echo "${NAME//\//\\\/}"    # => a\/b\/c\/d
```